# How to deal with the model output to compute the loss

Tags: python, keras, model

I am struggling to train the model in Keras, by minimizing the loss between the correct data and "input*output", but do not know how to deal with it.

Given that

X: model input (training data)

Y: model output

T: correct data

model = Model(inputs=X, outputs=Y)

Then, in my understanding,
model.fit(X,T) trains the model to minimize the distance between Y(=model(X)) and T, according to the user-defined loss function.

My question is:
What if I want to minimize the distance between Y*X and T?

I thought writing such as "model.fit(X * model.predict(X), T)" would work well? (It did not, actually)
I wonder how to write the code to do that.

Thank you for the advice in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Make a functional API model:

```
inputs = Input(input_shape)
outputs = SomeLayer(...)(inputs)
outputs = SomeLayer(...)(outputs)
outputs = SomeLayer(...)(outputs)
....

outputs = Multiply()([inputs, outputs])

model = Model(inputs, outputs)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=loss, metrics=metrics)

model.fit(X, T, ...)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.
According to your answer, the output seems multiplied one.
However, I want the model to output Y, BEFORE it is multiplied by input.